# Matplotlib - controlling space between first/last major tick and axes box?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Does anyone know how to manually control the "whitespace" or "pad" between the first/last major tick labels on the x and/or y axis and the edge of the axes box? For example, in the image below, I would be looking to the locate the first (x=0/y=0) and last (x=4/y=4) major ticks slightly offset from the edge of the axes:

[image: https://matplotlib.org/_images/anatomy.png]

Similar to what is shown here:

[image: https://matplotlib.org/_images/sphx_glr_usage_001.png]

Comment: [`plt.margins()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.margins.html),  if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: BigBen's comment will do the trick, for further customizing plots, have a look at the [customizing tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html)